# Nested Array Printing an inner array into an empty string - Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
address_book = [
['Company1','123 Mission Blvd', 'San Francisco','California', 12345, '415-555-4444','CompanyOne@companyone.com','https://company1.com'], 
['Company2','77 Market Street', 'San Francisco','California', 94111,'415-444 4444','Company2@company2.com','https://company2.com']
]
```

I have an address block here that I would like to iterate through and send to the below empty string.

```
email_temp = ""


address_book.each do |address_block|
  address_block.each do |company_name, address, city, state, zip, tel, email, web_address|
    email_temp << "Company Name: #{company_name} #{address} #{city} #{state} #{zip} Tel: #{tel} #{email} #{web_address}"
  end
end
```

I started off with ,the above but at every iteration it is printing the Company Name before every element of the inner array. How do I fix this? 
I want to keep it very simple. Just trying to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Where's that company name being printed? what's the simple one?

Comment: Probably there's missing code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following usage is not correct if array is single:

```rb
address_block.each do |company_name, address, city, state, zip, tel, email, web_address|
```

Because `address_block` is an array and only 1 argument passed to block as array member.

So you would change it with the following code snippet.

```rb
address_book.each do |address_block|
  email_temp << "Company Name: #{address_block.first} "
  email_temp << address_block[1..4].join(' ')
  email_temp << " Tel: #{address_block[5]} #{address_block[6..7].join(' ') }"
end
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to [@sebastian-palma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5025116/sebastian-palma), I have learned a new thing regarding to ruby blocks when it comes to nested arrays. So I update the solution for this question. But I do not recommend this solution due to code smells.

```rb
address_book.each do |company_name, address, city, state, zip, tel, email, web_address|
  email_temp << "Company Name: #{company_name} #{address} #{city} #{state} #{zip} Tel: #{tel} #{email} #{web_address}"
end
```

Comment: You can use just `address_book.each do |company_name, address, city, state, zip, tel, email, web_address| ... end`

Comment: Thank you, I have learned new thing. But the thing is this is valid for nested array.